# Watermark and join videos in bulk using ffmpeg

Tags: performance, powershell, video, batch

I have this batch file using ffmpeg to add a logo to my videos and then add an intro but it's taking anywhere from 10 hours to a day depending on how many I have to watermark, is there a more efficient way to achieve this? The videos sometimes have different resolutions so I can't remove the conversion to the 1280*720 size.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%I" -i white.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -y -i %%I -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -s 1280*720 %%I.ts && ffmpeg -y -i "concat:out1.ts|%%I.ts|out1.ts" -c:v libx264 -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -ar 48000 -r 20 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that in 2 separate loops? Can't the `ffmpeg` opearations done within a single one?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't figure out how, I tried using && to tie them together but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Looks like you need to enclose multiple statements in braces (`{}`)  like I found here:  http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-for-loop,2-845.html

Comment: Or use parens in case you're using the classic batch syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252979/windows-batch-call-more-than-one-command-in-a-for-loop